# What is the / is there any meaningful difference between the two spellings 'naive' and 'naïve'?

Tags: orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you always use the accent in foreign words like “résumé”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177/should-you-always-use-the-accent-in-foreign-words-like-resume)
>   [“Whereäs” as an alternative spelling of “whereas”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas)
>   [Is it spelt “naïve” or “naive”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12747/is-it-spelt-naive-or-naive)

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naive) lists both spellings without any comment on validity / usage. The second variant seems to be the French original, and the other the "anglified" version.

Is there even a slight, maybe stylistic, difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you always use the accent in foreign words like "résumé"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177/should-you-always-use-the-accent-in-foreign-words-like-resume); see also: [How should foreign words (with foreign characters) be written in English text?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9279/how-should-foreign-words-with-foreign-characters-be-written-in-english-text)

Comment: I'm under the impression that this word has an accent-free spelling. As tchrist said, this accent-free spelling is probably due to the lack of dieresis on many typewriters, at least in an historical perspective. However, I suggest you "naive" as primary spelling.

Comment: @coleopterist maybe 'related', but not 'possible duplicate'; sorry, but I disagree with you on voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The stylistic difference is that writing ***naïve*** without the diaeresis comes off as rough and slip-shod, almost careless.

There is no other word in English whose pronunciation would work that way, which is quite different from how ***waive*** works. That means that the price of a diaeresis is adding a brand new rule or exception to English.  That’s too high a price to pay.

A better spelling for those who can’t be bothered to write the diaeresis might be something ***nayeeve*** or even ***nigheve***, but no one writes that.